# How to make and add two date between range in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, json, swift, calendar, fscalendar

I am working on FSCalendar for displaying events colors on it. Now, I want to display date range.

```
{ frmdt = "2017-10-10"; hlddesc = "Diwali Vacation"; hldid = 20; hldnm = "Diwali Vacation"; todt = "2017-10-31"; }
```

this is one Array, I want to display colors on dates, fromdate - to dates (example: 10,11,12,13 etc.. upto 31).

It was working fine when I was passing a single date.

Comment: Anyone guide me how to solved issue ?

Comment: Hello, did you got any solution to this issue? I am facing same

Comment: @ZalakPatel Yes, I solved my problem. what did you get faced, tell me